# How to to pass a simple message from QML to HTML vice-versa on Android device using Qtwebview ,Qtwebsockets and Qtwebchannel

Tags: qt, qtandroidextras, qtwebview, qtwebchannel, qtwebsockets

The websocket did not open ,how to make it open and start the communication between the HTML to QML.

Iam unable to pass a simple message from QML to HTML vice-versa on Android device using Qtwebview ,Qtwebsockets and Qtwebchannel.

**Main Error :** I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(18)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: qt is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (18)

**Complete Error Log** - https://pastebin.com/FtaF2trH

for quick referance iam also attaching below pastebin urls:

Websocket.pro file - https://pastebin.com/s9iCt8UR

websockettransport.h file - https://pastebin.com/YgMVTdPw

main.cpp file - https://pastebin.com/x9LF42nc

index.html file - https://pastebin.com/kNkBjcaP

qwebchannel.js file - https://pastebin.com/zDL2SA6T

Compilation environment details are as follows:

QtVersion -5.12.12

Kit – Android Qt 5.12.12 Clang arm64-v8a

JDK – java-8-openjdk-amd64

SDK Version: 8.0

NDK Version: 21.3.6528147

Steps i have followed to compile this & run on Android:

Step 1 - I have included webview, webchannel in websockets in the websocket. Pro file

Step 2 – i have added the required index.html, bootstrap.min.css and the qtwebchannel.js in the android asset folder like this

```
deployment.files += android_asset/index.html
deployment.files += android_asset/bootstrap.min.css
deployment.files += android_asset/qwebchannel.js
deployment.path = /assets
INSTALLS += deployment
```

what i expect:  The websocket did not open ,how to make it open and start the communication between the HTML to QML

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Rajesh! Your question needs a few improvements in order to not be closed/downvoted, because it does not respect this site's rules. Please include all code into your question, but preferably in the form of a [mre]. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and visit the [help] to better understand how you could benefit from this site and the experts that ***volunteer*** here.